# ValueError: No module named 'notmigrations' during unit tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, multi-tenant, django-unittest

I have django application 2.1.7 with django-tenant plugin (creating schemas in the database for saas).

My problem is unit testing. I run the command:
`python manage.py test --settings=project.settings_test`
and I'm getting a error: `ImportError: No module named 'notmigrations'`

My code in settings_test file

```
from .settings_base import *


class DisableMigrations(object):
    def __contains__(self, item):
        return True

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return 'notmigrations'

MIGRATION_MODULES = DisableMigrations()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using an ancient hack intended for really old versions of Django (< 1.9), from before there was support to disable migrations in testing. Since you're now using a relatively recent version of Django (2.1.7), delete that code from your test settings module.

Should you want to disable migrations in tests, use [the modern approach, which is putting the value to `None` in `MIGRATION_MODULES` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#migration-modules).

> When you supply `None` as a value for an app, Django will consider the app as an app without migrations regardless of an existing migrations submodule. This can be used, for example, in a test settings file to skip migrations while testing (tables will still be created for the apps’ models).

```
# test_settings.py
from settings import *

MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'auth': None,
    'contenttypes': None,
    'sessions': None,
    ...
    'myapp1': None,
    'myapp2': None,
}
```